# regular expression operators

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following regular expression with which I match a few lines.

Here is an example:

```
field1    xyz
field2    yiuyi
field3    12.34.12
```

This is my regex:

```
static string partPattern = @"^(?<Key>\w*)\s+(?<Value>\w*)$";
```

This is the code I use:

```
Match m = Regex.Match(line, partPattern);
if (m.Groups["Key"].Length > 0 && m.Groups["Value"].Length > 0)
{
    //add to Dictionary 
}
```

It works fine in all cases except when there is a date. I just wanted to make it so that it fetches the values regardless of blank, quotes, or anything else.

Comment: From your example, it looks like a fixed-width implementation would be simpler (and perhaps faster) than using a Regex. But perhaps you are not able to share everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using word characters (`\w`), which include `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, but you probably want to match any character, at least for the `Value`.

```
^(?<Key>\w+)\s+(?<Value>.+)$
```

Comment: I updated the code, basically I'm  adding to a dictionary, the values of a line

Comment: @tammy: Well, I don't know what signifance the code has to the question, but I might point out that my version of the regex does not require the `if` statement.

Comment: @tammy: If this answers your question, please mark it as answered.